# Auto-implement persistence/clone functionality in DTO classes

Tags: .net, reflection, code-generation, dto, codedom

I need to create DTO objects which holds simple properties and needs to implement the following functionality:

- Load From XML node
- Save to XML node
- Clone

Programming these function is each DTO over and over again would be very tedious and error prone I think so I though about alternatives.

1. Use Reflection, would be very slow I guess
2. C# Code generation as pre- or postbuild step (both would require building the solution twice, since I need a compiled class to get info which code to generate)
3. Use CodeDom? I think this is the most complicated solution

What is the best/simplest common way to accomplish such a task? How Can I determine which one to chose or are there alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load and save from XML using `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` and the `Deserialize` and `Serialize` methods.

Cloning can be performed by [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).